# MySQL ORDER BY only returns one row

Tags: mysql

This is my code :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Event_list 
WHERE interest in 
  (
   SELECT Interest_name 
   from Interest 
   where Interest_id in 
     (
      SELECT Interest_id 
      FROM `User's Interests` 
      where P_id=Pid and is_canceled=0
     )
  )
order by count(Eid) desc
```

I don't use any `GROUP BY` clause but still only get one row. when removing the `ORDER BY` clause I get all the correct rows (but not in the right order).

I'm trying to return a view (named `Event_list`) sorted by most common `Eid` (Event id), but I want to see every row without any grouping.

Comment: Your query is not syntacticly correct (`User's Interests`?).  Please fix the query.  Provide sample data and the results it is producing.  A SQL Fiddle example is welcome.  Also, qualify all your column names, so someone reading the question knows what table they are coming from.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the table name is fine; OP has it in backticks, so there's no syntax error there.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually, the backticks were in OP's original question. See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30547005/revisions

Comment: Hi, it's not a syntax error, just using backticks. I'm new here and not sure how to edit posts. Thanks.

Comment: can you explain please? not sure I understand

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT()` is a group function, so using it will automatically result in grouping of rows. This is why you get only one row in your result when you use it in your `ORDER BY` clause.

Unfortunately, it's not clear what you're trying to do, so I can't tell you how to rewrite your query to get your desired results.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'm trying to return a view (named Event_list) sorted by most common Eid (Event id), but I want to see every row without any grouping.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the query you want is more like this:

```
SELECT el.*,
       (select count(*)
        from interest i join
             UserInterests ui
             on ui.is_canceled = 0 and ui.p_id = i.id
        where el.interest = i.interest_name
       ) as cnt
FROM Event_list el
ORDER BY cnt desc;
```

It is a bit hard to tell without sample data and a better formed query.  Some notes:

- Don't use special characters in table and column names.  Having to escape the names merely leads to queries that are harder to read, write, and understand.
- Qualify column names, so you know what tables columns come from.
- Use table aliases -- so queries are easier to write and to read.
- The `WHERE` clause only does filtering.  Your description of the problem doesn't seem to involve filtering, only ordering.
- Any time you use an aggregation function, the query automatically becomes an aggregation query.  Without a `group by`, exactly one row is returned.
- Give foreign keys the same names as primary keys, where possible.

Comment: and use common entity naming such that you don't need to remember that event_list.interest = interest.interest_name.  And don't write correlated subqueries. Here is why: it is like you are trying to think it thru for the db optimizer, as opposed to letting it do its magic. Will take 10 minute queries down to seconds on large datasets

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. all cnt values are 1 and it's not sorted the way it should.

Comment: @DrewPierce . . . That is worth adding to the list.  Thank you.

Comment: @maayanpeleg . . . You should set up a SQL Fiddle (www.sqlfiddle.com) with your tables and (sample) data.  That would help other help you.

Comment: @maayanpeleg, perhaps it is just a step or two away if you give more info. schema, data sample, expected output

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
SELECT L.* , C.Cnt
FROM Event_list L
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT E.EID, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
  FROM Event_List E 
  JOIN Interest I
  ON E.Interest = I.Interest_name 
  JOIN `User's Interests` U
  ON U.Interest_id  = I.Insert_Id
  Where U.P_id=Pid and U.is_canceled=0
  GROUP BY E.EID
) C
ON E.Eid = C.Eid
Order By Cnt DESC
```

I don't have the tables to test so you may want to correct column names and other conditions. Just provide you the idea.